# Permanently gain extra Psionic powers

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

I am aware of the ability to temporarily gain Psionic powers from other users as well as the Expanded knowledge feat.

I am looking for an ability or ritual that allows a Psionic to learn extra powers like a wizard can learn new spells.

I am simply looking for something rules based before I attempt to do something homebrew.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am simply looking for something rules based before I attempt to do something homebrew.

Sadly, you're not going to find something "rules-based", because it simply doesn't work within the balance of the game. Psions are already quite competitive with Wizards and Sorcerers. Giving them an outright "spellbook" option would make them the single most powerful class in the game.

Just quickly compare Psions to Wizards and Sorcerers (*their two closest counterparts*).

**Wizards**

- get a limited number of spells / day (*max 4 / spell level*)
- can learn lots of potential spells (*given the funds to do so*)
- get new spell levels at character level 3,5,7...

**Sorcerers**

- get a high number of spells / day (*max 6 / spell level*)
- can know only a limited number of total spells
- get new spell levels at character level 4,6,8...

**Psions**

- get a point pool, but if you add it up, it's roughly between Wizards and Sorcerers. It's actually higher at low levels.
- can know only a limited number of total spells, but that number is greater than the Sorcerer.
- get new spells levels at character level 3,5,7...

**Some subtle trade-offs**

- Sorcerers tend to know a lot of "less useful" spells. A 7th level sorcerer has 10 spells known (5/3/2), while the Psion has 15. The sorcerer can cast Fireball 4 times (7d6), but the Psion can cast it 6 times (7d6). Psions can use their most powerful spells more.
- Most Psion combat spells scale DC and damage. They cost more points to cast, but your "Fireball" (*aka Energy Ball*) has a tougher save as you level up the damage. Fireball tends to become weak in later levels because the DC becomes so low that most creatures can save. Sorcerers end up having to pick up Delayed Blast Fireball just to get a higher DC.
- Several Psion abilities actually scale "within themselves" giving you a virtual two-for-one or three-for-one deal.  Take a look at [Dispel Psionics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/d/dispel-psionics). It is effectively Dispel Magic + Dispel Magic, Greater for the price of one spell slot.
- Because Psion spells "scale", the use of "Metamagic" Feats is much more limited. This means that you can often spend your feats elsewhere (like on even more spells).

Hopefully it's clear by now that these elements are designed with some balance in mind.

**If you want to homebrew...**

The easiest model is simply to tweak the Psion class to re-balance the trade-offs.

- Drop the number of Power Points to bring it inline with Wizard "spells / day".
- Change the first level "bonus feat" to "scribe scroll" (*aka Power Stones*).
- Drop the "Discipline Abilities" as these are effectively Sorcerer Bloodlines.
- "Arcane Bond" stays pretty much the same.
- Use the Wizard "spells / day" table for the number of distinct spells that can be memorized.

Note that in some ways, this Wizard Psion may be more powerful than a regular Wizard (*already the second strongest class in the game*). You may need to tweak this to "power down" the Wizard Psion.

Answer (score 6):

The best one I can find is the [Expanded Knowledge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/expanded-knowledge-psionic) feat, from Dreamscarred Press. It's part of Psionics Unleashed.

Answer (score 5):

The Telepath 9th tier power: Psychic Chirurgery - You repair psychic damage or impart knowledge of new powers.

Psions have a limited number of powers along the lines of Bards and Sorcerers - limited powers, but can use them as much as they want. Psions are even more powerful with the use of Power Points that can be allocated in any fashion towards any ends within their chosen Powers.

IF Psychic Chirurgery is available in Pathfinder, there may be restrictions on its use or availability. It may also be altered from the SRD version. Please check all available sources - campaign and otherwise.

If the SRD version stands, you either need to be a Telepath or have a Telepath use it for/on you. Once two Psions have the power, they can effectively "trade" powers.

Besides Telepath Psions, Vitalists also get Psychic Chirurgery on their class lists. As a last resort, if unable to find a Vitalist, Telepath, or character who gained Psychic Chirurgery through a use of Psychic Chirurgery (perhaps you want a power only available to classes that don't get lvl9s at all), you can always buy a power stone, and combine it with whatever buffs (perhaps from further consumables purchases) are necessary to allow whomever you do find with the desired power to use the stone successfully. Expensive, but it can be done.

Answer (score 4):

The following ways to add new powers to your Powers Known exist:

- The Extra Power feat
- The Expanded Knowledge feat
- The Psychic Chirurgery power

Technically you could research new powers which are added to your Powers Known, but this is completely under the virtue of the GM, for a good reason. In a world where this is commonplace, it changes how the entire game works and its associated balance - if the GM wants that, the option is there.

Comment: We're doing a revision of Psionics Unleashed, should we in this case include any specific wording to make this extra clear?

Answer (score 0):

Never underestimate Psychic Reformation. Don't have that situational power? 10 minutes later you do.