# Does a "Page of Knowledge"-item exist for the Wilder class?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, psionics

The Wilder class's most weak point is their known powers. This is similair to Sorcerers. Sorcerers can fill this gap up a little, by purchasing the Page of Knowledge-item, which grants a specific spell as "known"

Does such an item also exist for Wilders? And if not, what would be a fair/balanced price be taking into comparison that powers could also be augmented.

Comment: Could not locate a magic item for it, but there is a feat you could take: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/expanded-knowledge-psionic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Official Rules

#### You can use another manifester's powers

Not really an item, per se, but a way of gaining more powers without leveling up or spending feats.

See the [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers#TOC-Manifest-an-Unknown-Power-from-Another-s-powers-Known):

> #### Manifest an Unknown Power from Another's powers Known
>
> A psionic character can attempt to manifest a power from a source other than his own knowledge (usually another willing psionic character).<sup>**1**</sup> To do so, the character must first make contact (a process similar to addressing a power stone, requiring a Spellcraft check against a DC of 20). A psionic character can make contact with only a willing psionic character or creature (unconscious creatures are considered willing, but not psionic characters under the effects of other immobilizing conditions). Characters that can’t use power stones for any reason are also banned from attempting to manifest powers from the knowledge of other psionic characters. Mental contact requires 1 full round of physical contact, which can provoke attacks of opportunity. Once contact is achieved, the character becomes aware of all the powers the other character knows up to the highest level of power the contactor knows himself. Next, the psionic character must choose one of the powers and make a second Spellcraft check (DC 15 + the power’s level) to see if he understands it. If the power is not on his class list, he automatically fails this check.
>
> Upon successfully making contact with another willing psionic character or creature and learning what he can of one power in particular, the character can immediately attempt to manifest that power even if he doesn’t know it (and assuming he has power points left for the day). He can attempt to manifest the power normally on his next turn, and he succeeds if he makes one additional Spellcraft check (DC 15 + the power’s level). He retains the ability to manifest the selected power for only 1 round. If he doesn’t manifest the power, fails the Spellcraft check, or manifests a different power, he loses his chance to manifest that power, although he does not spend any power points unless he successfully manifests a power.
>
> Whether this process results in a successful manifestation of a power or not, the entire process must be performed every time a character wants to manifest a power from another’s powers known.

So either take powers from your friends, or knock out enemy manifesters and carry them around. Keeping them unconscious is fairly easy; just apply some Ability Drain on their Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma to get it to 0, and they can't wake up until someone magically restores it. Then the only tricky part is keeping them in a way that's portable and accessible, without having to lug them around. The [recent question about trapping people](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/32047/4563) may be useful, though do note that it is for 3.5; some details may be different in *Pathfinder*.

Also, be aware that this process is not exactly quick; you need several Spellcraft checks and it takes a few rounds.

#### Get the Student's Surge

The Student's Surge gives you four extra Expanded Knowledge feats (as well as Psicrystal Affinity), which is a *really* nice expansion of your power repertoire. May require some retraining, though.

### Houserules

#### Restore this ability to Power Stones

I want to point out that in the 3.5 version of these rules, the parenthetical marked <sup>**1**</sup> above said "usually a **power stone** or another willing psionic character" (**emphasis** mine), which allowed for power stones to be used with your own power points to avoid burning the stones. Unfortunately, this option seems to have been removed. Probably because it never really made sense with the rest of the section, which is constantly talking about the "character or creature" and never again mentions the stones.

Thus the cost of gaining another power known was power level × manifester level × 25 gp, but do note that the process of accessing the power was fairly time-consuming, as is accessing another's power. Plus the stone could be used like a scroll if you were out of power points/didn't have time to do the whole thing.

#### Homebrew a psionic version of the Page of Knowledge

Spells and powers are pretty similar (spells typically being a bit better, particularly lower-level spells that scale automatically with caster level while powers require more power points spent), so the same cost of (power level)<sup>2</sup> × 1,000 gp seems pretty fair, or at least as fair as the Page of Knowledge is. I suggest some kind of stone or crystal, in keeping with the themes of psionics. Power Crystal, perhaps? Make it seem like a refinement of the power stone.

Comment: You said:"Keeping them unconscious is fairly easy; just apply some Ability Drain on their Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma to get it to 0, and they can't wake up until someone magically restores it." Does this mean that ability score does not restore when being unconcious? It was my understanding ability scores restore 1 point per day?

Comment: @Jeff Ability **damage** does. Ability drain does not. Ability drain has to be magically cured.

Comment: thank you for stating the difference. I'm having a hard time thinking of spells that actually do ability drain below 1. Most (if not all?) spells drain with minimum of 1 such as Bestow Curse.

Comment: @Jeff The easiest way is to have someone *create* / *summon* / *command* / Rebuke the appropriate undead creatures (allips are a favorite).

Comment: since I have no clue how I can personally message you on RPG Stackexchange, I'm trying via this way. Could I invite you to have a look here? http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47594/what-would-be-a-potential-balanced-mythic-version-of-psionic-power-mind-thrust

Comment: @Jeff You can't personally message anyone. Anyway, I know nothing about the Mythic rules, so I cannot assist with that question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic item that I know of that does this.

However, if you wanted to make one, I estimate the base cost as being twice what the comparable [Page of Knowledge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/page-of-spell-knowledge) is or (spell level)<sup>2</sup> × 2,000 gp

My logic is as follows:

Super Genius Games introduced the feat [Extra Spells Known](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/super-genius-games/general-feats/extra-spells-known) which adds 2 spells to a spontaneous casters spells known. This feat is twice as powerful as the psionic feat [Expanded Knowledge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/expanded-knowledge-psionic). This tells us that each arcane spell known is half as valuable as a psionic power known, so a magic item that provides an extra power should be twice what the cost of a spell is.

Comment: Using a third-party source to balance another third-party source is **extremely** dubious. Worse, Extra Spells Known does not specify whether or not the spells you learn must come from your own list or not (the same problem the 3.5 Extra Spell has), which will lead to arguing and also makes it hard to compare to Expanded Knowledge which can explicitly get you another class's power. Moreover, regardless of what Super Genius Games did, learning a power is **not** more valuable than learning a spell, so the same price makes the most sense.

Comment: @KRyan Sorcerers gain at least 1 spell known per level (almost always at least 1 is of their highest level available). Wilders gain 1 power every two levels. I see twice the cost for something you naturally gain half of as pretty balanced.

Comment: I see a class that gets the same thing but at half the rate as underpowered and in need of a break.

Comment: @ColinD While I think your answer has good argumentation and the pricing makes sense.. I tend to follow KRyan's argumentation. The decisive factor in this is that it's elementary that Wilder is behind it's kin-classes like Psion. Next to this, this Item is also usable by Psion, which do get powers every level.

Answer (score 0):

There is a strong argument, by way of the magic-psionics transparency rules, that the Page of Spell Knowledge itself is, in fact, the exact item you are looking for. A particularly strict interpretation of the RAW would still forbid this, but only on the somewhat shaky grounds that the item description specifies "arcane or divine" spell. However, it should be pretty easy to make a reasonable case to the GM in favor of this. Note that the fluff for the item does not at all fit the default fluff for psionics, so assuming you are using the latter, you might want to refluff it into a refined version of a power stone or some such, particularly since the original gives clear parallels as a refined version of the power stone's Vancian counterpart, the scroll.

Comment: Can I please get a comment on why I was downvoted? I can't improve if I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

> Does such an item also exist for Wilders?

So technically, via "Magic / Psionic" transparency, this item probably works "as written". The only challenge questionable part is the line about "Spontaneous Caster".

If we read "Spontaneous Caster" as "Charisma-based caster", then this applies to the Wilder and it is completely valid to simply have this item work as-is.

> And if not, what would be a fair/balanced price be taking into comparison that powers could also be augmented?

Please take a look at the [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31544/) that deals with Psions learning spells like Wizards. Psionic spells scale a little differently. a first-level Wizard spell like Burning Hands will max out at 5d4 and has limited use at higher levels. A first-level Psion/Wilder spell like [Energy Ray](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/e/energy-ray) will scale with the # of points spent on casting it and will frankly be good "forever". I was happily launching Energy Rays at 16th level.

If you look at "Spells Known" for Wilder, they have about 50% of the # of spells the Sorcerer has. At higher levels, even less.

If you make the Psionic version cost 2x the Arcane/Divine version, I think you'll get a relatively balanced item.

Comment: Can you cite relevant sections of the Psionics-Magic Transparency rules? I originally wrote my answer along similar lines, but wound up rejecting the interpretation because I didn't see the rules I felt were necessary to back it up.

Comment: Also, your comparison of *burning hands* and *energy ray* is fallacious because you ignore the Power Point costs of an Augmented *energy ray* versus the *burning hands*. Even at 5d4 damage, *burning hands* **still** uses a 1st-level spell slot. To get good damage at 16th level from *energy ray*, you need to use 16 Power Points: the equivalent of an 8th-level spell slot.

Comment: So you're just quoting the Psionics/Magic trade-off. My point is clearly that access to one Psi Power is probably worth more than access to a single Spell. There is no first level spell I can learn that will ever deal 16d6 damage. So regardless of the fact of "knowing" that spell, it does tend to become useless over time. Most Psi powers remain useful as the PC levels and that's the point I was trying to make.

Comment: Being cha-based and being spontaneous are two things that just happen to coincide very frequently, but are not directly relevant to each other. Wilders can pick individual powers when they are cast, without choosing ahead of time which ones to cast how many times that day, thus they are spontaneous. The much bigger issue from a strict RAW standpoint is that the item specifies "arcane or divine" spells, and psionic powers are neither arcane, nor divine.